# For every string in file1.txt check if it exists in file2.txt then do something

Tags: string, shell

I got two txt file, file1.txt and file2.txt. 
Both of them have one single string for each line. Strings in file1.txt are uniqe (no duplication), as well as strings in file2.txt. 
The files have different numbers of strings.

```
file1.txt                 file2.txt

FFF                       AAA
GGG                       BBB 
ZZZ                       CCC
                          ZZZ
```

I'd like to compare those files, so that for every string in file1.txt, if it exists in file2.txt than it's ok. If not, than write that string in another file (file3.txt)

In this example, file3.txt would be:

```
file3.txt

FFF
GGG
```

I'd like to use the command shell, doing something like:

```
cat file1.txt | while read a; do something on file2.txt ...
```

but that is not compulsory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the man page for grep, specifically the -f option.

```
grep -vf file2.txt file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to read in the input from file 2, put it in a sorted list (or even better, a balanced search tree) and then as you read in each line from file1, go through the tree or do a binary search of the list to find if the string exists.

The idea is that you want to do processing once to make the list of allowed values as easy to check as possible.  Putting them in a binary search tree would mean that you first compare it against the word in the middle (alphabetically) of list 2, if it is before it, you take the left branch (which contains words that come before the word you just compared to, or if it comes after, you only have to look at the right branch.

Similarly, if using a list, you look at the word in the middle of the list and then can remove half of the remaining list from consideration each iteration.  This means you only have to do log n steps to check each of the words in List1 against the n words in list2.